How to call .seek method for inner created Consumer with Camel pulsar lib
I'm using camel-pulsar library to build a pulsar client to consume data, but need to add a replay function incase of losing data. what I used to do is call seek method for consumer in pulsar client to determind when to start consuming data. but not sure if camel pulsar also support this?
camel pulsar version i'm using is 3.22.0
